# Run-time error '13' - Type Mismatch doing a Find

Tags: excel, vba, range

I've written the below code for some ActiveX textboxes I have on a worksheet that pull in data from another sheet and are controlled with a couple of buttons (previous and next).

All works good except for I keep getting the following error:

> Run-time error '13':
>
> Type mismatch

It's strange because the cells only contain text and are formatted as text, so I'm not sure why I keep getting the type mismatch.

The lines that cause the errors are:

```
Set sectionfound = .Find(what:=sectiontextbox.Object.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

```
Set titlefound = .Find(what:=titletextbox.Object.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

```
Set controlfound = .Find(what:=controltextbox.Object.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

```
Set guidancefound = .Find(what:=guidancetextbox.Object.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

The whole sub:

```
Sub UpdateTextBox(shift As Long)

Dim sectionfound As Range
Dim titlefound As Range
Dim controlfound As Range
Dim guidancefound As Range
Dim titlerange As Range
Dim sectionrange As Range
Dim controlrange As Range
Dim guidancerange As Range
Dim commentsrange As Range
Dim titletextbox As OLEObject
Dim sectiontextbox As OLEObject
Dim controltextbox As OLEObject
Dim guidancetextbox As OLEObject
Dim commentstextbox As OLEObject
Dim index As Long

With Worksheets("Tool")
    Set sectiontextbox = .OLEObjects("Section_Textbox")
    Set sectionrange = Worksheets("Annex_A").Range("B3:B165")
    Set titletextbox = .OLEObjects("Title_Textbox")
    Set titlerange = Worksheets("Annex_A").Range("C3:C165")
    Set controltextbox = .OLEObjects("Control_Textbox")
    Set controlrange = Worksheets("Annex_A").Range("D3:D165")
    Set guidancetextbox = .OLEObjects("Guidance_Textbox")
    Set guidancerange = Worksheets("Annex_A").Range("E3:E165")
    Set commentstextbox = .OLEObjects("Comments_Textbox")
    Set commentsrange = Worksheets("Annex_A").Range("F3:F165")
End With

With sectionrange
    If sectiontextbox.Object.Text <> "" Then
        Set sectionfound = .Find(what:=sectiontextbox.Object.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not sectionfound Is Nothing Then index = sectionfound.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1
    End If

    index = index + shift
    Select Case index
        Case Is > .Rows.Count
            index = .Rows.Count
        Case Is < 1
            index = 1
    End Select

    sectiontextbox.Object.Text = .Rows(index)
End With

With titlerange
    If titletextbox.Object.Text <> "" Then
        Set titlefound = .Find(what:=titletextbox.Object.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not titlefound Is Nothing Then index = titlefound.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1
    End If

    index = index + shift
    Select Case index
        Case Is > .Rows.Count
            index = .Rows.Count
        Case Is < 1
            index = 1
    End Select

    titletextbox.Object.Text = .Rows(index)
End With

With controlrange
    If controltextbox.Object.Text <> "" Then
        Set controlfound = .Find(what:=controltextbox.Object.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not controlfound Is Nothing Then index = controlfound.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1
    End If

    index = index + shift
    Select Case index
        Case Is > .Rows.Count
            index = .Rows.Count
        Case Is < 1
            index = 1
    End Select

    controltextbox.Object.Text = .Rows(index)
End With

With guidancerange
    If guidancetextbox.Object.Text <> "" Then
        Set guidancefound = .Find(what:=guidancetextbox.Object.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not guidancefound Is Nothing Then index = guidancefound.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1
    End If

    index = index + shift
    Select Case index
        Case Is > .Rows.Count
            index = .Rows.Count
        Case Is < 1
            index = 1
    End Select

    guidancetextbox.Object.Text = .Rows(index)
End With

End Sub


Private Sub Next_Button_Click()
UpdateTextBox -1
End Sub

Private Sub Previous_Button_Click()
UpdateTextBox 1
End Sub
```

Comment: You should not be getting that particular error on these particular lines, and I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Would you put the line `msgbox sectiontextbox.Object.Text` before the first error line, run it, and report back the results?

Comment: @n8. The errors are at different points. So the first one that errors is the guidancetextbox. When putting the messagebox in, it shows the data correctly, until it gets to the first cell that breaks it (E6). I've even tried just putting 'test' into E6 incase it was the data in the cell breaking it. But it still errors out on that one first. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's an important clue

Comment: So the text that kicks back in the msgbox in that case is as expected?

Comment: Can't reproduce this...

Comment: We're doing important work here.  For new users who get what they want and never return.

Comment: @n8. Apologies but I've been travelling over the weekend. In reply to your question, yes, the message box pulls back the data as expected until the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should have this code only once in the sub:

```
index = index + shift
Select Case index
    Case Is > 165 '.Rows.Count
        index = 165 '.Rows.Count
    Case Is < 1
        index = 1
End Select
```

Without seeing the form or the data it doesn't make sense that you would iterate the row multiple times, it seems like the row is supposed to move only one per the `shift` parameter.

I would put this after your `With Worksheets("Tool")` block and before your `With sectionrange` block

My theory is that these multiple iterations are causing the sub to attempt to look beyond the declared range, a row that is greater than 165.

**EDIT**

**EDIT** **EDIT**

I added a series of message boxes to let us understand what happens, step by step.

Try this, let me know what happens?

```
With guidancerange
        msgbox("guidancetextbox.Object.Text row: """ & guidancetextbox.Object.Text & """") 

    If guidancetextbox.Object.Text <> "" Then
        Index = .Find(what:=guidancetextbox.Object.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        msgbox("Index row: """ & Index & """") 
        msgbox(".Rows(1).Row + 1: """ & .Rows(1).Row + 1 & """") 
    End If

    Index = Index + shift
    msgbox(".Rows.Count: """ & .Rows.Count & """") 
    Select Case Index + shift
        Case Is > .Rows.Count
            Index = .Rows.Count
        Case Is < 1
            Index = 1
    End Select

    msgbox("Index row: """ & Index & """") 
    guidancetextbox.Object.Text = .Rows(Index)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I like your theory! However putting the above in between those two sections does not compile unless I put it in another 'with' statement. If I do put it inside a with statement, no text at all is changed when pressing the button. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Since all of your ranges end at 165 I hard-coded 165 where it matters, this will allow your code to run. `.Rows.Count` needed an object to get a max row count.  This is strictly for debugging.  Incidentally, will there ever be a case where those ranges will have a different max row?

Comment: With 165 hard-coded, there are no compiler issues, however none of the text box data changes when pressing the button. I can confirm that the maximum row will always be 165 as it is a set amount of data that I am trying to display.

Comment: Could you describe in your post what each of those `With` block algorithms do?  I have a feeling that there is a more concise path to your goal.

Comment: The purpose of this bit in specific isn't clear to me: `index = sectionfound.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1`

Comment: It doesn't look like you're trapping the "match not found" condition.

Comment: It was an ex-colleague who set this up so I'm slightly in the lurch here. I have a spreadsheet with two sheets. One contains 4 columns, where each row contains text data for 165 rows (called Annex_A). There is then a second sheet which has 4 active X text boxes and three buttons. The purpose of this sheet is to pull each row of data from Annex A into the text boxes on the "Tool" sheet. Navigation is then controlled by three buttons, Home - which takes it back to the first row, Previous & Next - which which go to the next row down or previous row. The idea is that that it is much easier to read

Comment: My understanding is that the 'with' blocks read in their specific part from the 'Annex A' sheet. I believe that the line you are unsure of is to increment the row for each of the 4 parts each time? Although I could be wrong.

Comment: OK I took some of the steps out that seemed "extra", please try it out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it. With your updated code, the increment button (next), skips two entries and then I get the type mismatch error.

Comment: I added some message boxes, try these and look at the values for each step.  It might start to make sense where the issue is.